# Writing String into a File

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm implementing a WebScript using Alfresco's JavaScript. l'm trying to insert string to a file, but I can't do it.

When I write another file's content like:

```
file.properties.content.write(content);
```

It works, and the file's contents are copied into my file. But I can't insert string directly, like:

```
file.properties.content.write("Stuff like that");
```

it gives an exception. How can I write string into this file?

Comment: 'write(string) is undefined' kind of exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it, thanks to a guy from Alfresco forums.
We need to set it versionable, then assigning the content writes into the file. It goes like:

```
var doc = userhome.createFile("checkmeout.txt");
doc.addAspect("cm:versionable");
doc.content = "original text";
```